# Footnote: How to add given name initials in citations?

Tags: biblatex, citing, footnotes

Hello dear LaTex Community!

I have footnotes with only the surname. How can I get the footnotes to have the initial of the first given name in there?
I tried to add following:

```
\DeclareNameFormat[citename]{\namepartfamily, \namepartgiveni \dot}
```

this is the rest of my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[font = footnotesize]{caption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{acronym}
%\usepackage[flushmargin,hang,ragged]{footmisc}
\usepackage[breaklinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[flushmargin,hang,ragged]{footmisc} 
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{0pt}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage[left=6cm,right=1.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
%Literaturverzeichnis Settings
\usepackage{csquotes}
%\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-icomp,citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-ibid, uniquename=true]{biblatex}


\addbibresource{./Mtax.bib}
\DeclareDelimFormat{finalnamedelim}{\addspace \slash \space}
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib, biblist]{multinamedelim}{\space \slash \space}
\DeclareDelimAlias*[bib, biblist]{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space} 

\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamegiven}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\let\lastnameformat=\textsc
\let\firstnameformat=\textsc




\interfootnotelinepenalty=9999 % kein Seitenumbruch bei Fußnoten

\author{xxx}
\title{Thema}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}



\newgeometry{left=4cm,right=1.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2cm} 
    \begin{titlepage}
bla bla             
\end{titlepage}

\pagenumbering{Roman}

\tableofcontents

    \pagenumbering{arabic}

\restoregeometry
\newpage
\section{bla}
bla\footnote{vgl. \cite{Eilers}, Rz. 5}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{10pt}

\newpage
\printbibliography


\end{document}
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a custom name format and changing the cite commands to use this format:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-ibid, uniquename=true,giveninits=true,]{biblatex}


\DeclareCiteCommand{\footcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{fcite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}

\renewbibmacro*{fcite}{%
  \global\boolfalse{cbx:loccit}%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
       {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
           \setunit{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}
          {\printnames[mynameformat]{labelname}%
           \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}    

\newbibmacro*{cite:labeldate+extradate}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[bibhyperref]{\mkbibparens{\printlabeldateextra}}}}    


\DeclareNameFormat{mynameformat}{%
    \usebibmacro{name:family-given}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiveni}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}%
    \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

bla\footcite[vgl.][Rz. 5]{einstein}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Steffen, thanks for your answer. It works fine, but the problem is, that from the style= authoryear-ibid now the year is not printed anymore. Could you tell me why that happened and what I have to add? I can't figure it out.

Comment: Add-on: it should be Family-Name, Given Name (only initial). (year), p. x-x

Comment: @Victoria please check again, I made some modifications

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works perfect.